# Filtering is not working after upgrading from Angular 5 to 6

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

The following code worked for me until I upgraded Angular from 5 to 6.

Object Class:

```
export class Gizmo{
  name: string;
  description: string;

  constructor(name?: string, desc?: string) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = desc;
  }
}
```

Service:

```
  findGizmos(gizmoFindParams: GizmoFindParameters): Observable<Gizmo[]> {
    return this.http
      .get<Gizmo[]>(this.uriVar + "",
        {
          params: this.SetParameters(gizmoFindParams)
        });
  };
```

Component Method:

```
filterGizmoData(searchString?: string): Observable<Gizmo[]> {

    let tfp = new GizmoFindParameters(); 

    if (searchString != undefined) {
      tfp.value = searchString.trim();
    }

    return this.dataCatalogService.findGizmos(tfp).pipe(
    map(x => x.filter(y => !this.detail.detailItem.gizmos.includes(y.name))));
  };
```

What the code should be doing.

The service will return Observable array of Gizmo.

For example:

```
Gizmo1
Gizmo2
Gizmo3
Gizmo4
```

Prior to the method call the this.detail.detailItem.gizmos contain the values

```
Gizmo2
Gizmo3
```

When I call filterGizmoData I would expect it to return

```
Gizmo1
Gizmo4
```

Instead it is returning the entire list of Gizmos.

As I stated this worked when my project was Angular 5.
This was the code at that time.

```
   return this.dataCatalogService.findGizmos(tfp)
   .map(x =>       
      x.filter(y => !this.detail.detailItem.gizmos.includes(y.name))
    );
```

How can I get this code to work in Angular 6?

Also there is no errors in the console window.

EDIT (Showing import as requested):

```
import { tap, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, startWith ,  map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

EDIT 2 (Added code as requested)

```
private filterGizmos: Observable<Gizmo[]>;
//Various parts of my program do this:
this.filterGizmos = this.filterGizmoData();
```

Template:

```
<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let gizmo of filterGizmos | async" [value]="gizmo.name" (onSelectionChange)="gizmoSelectionChange(gizmo)">
        {{gizmo.name}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
```

Comment: What is getting returned now?

Comment: how are you importing your `map` operator

Comment: Vlad - As I stated the entire list gizmo1, gizmo2, gizmo3, gizmo4 is being returned.

Comment: Keshan - See edit please.

Comment: @JDS can you provide the template, or the place where filterGizmoData is being called?

Comment: Please see edit

Comment: I can't see anything obvious wrong @JDS - can you change the filter to `x.filter((y) => { console.log(y.name); console.log(!this.detail.detailItem.gizmos.includes(y.name); return !this.detail.detailItem.gizmos.includes(y.name); })` and check what gets logged on the console? That should let you see what the filter is doing...

Comment: Hmmm.  It appears that I get undefined for the y.name

Comment: Thanks Mark.  It appears that my code was fine.  After the debug suggestion I was able to pinpoint it to the return object being changed on the API side.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the docs for RXJS 6, this is an RXJS issue. there are two solutions.

1. add `rxjs-compat` to add backwards compatability to RXJS 5 or lower.
2. In RXJS 6, operators are to be always run inside pipe, so...

This should work, however why would you filter inside the map operator when you have a filter operator?

```
return this.dataCatalogService.findGizmos(tfp)
    .pipe(
        map(y => !this.detail.detailItem.gizmos.includes(y.tag))
    )
```

or

```
return this.dataCatalogService.findGizmos(tfp)
    .pipe(
        filter(y => !this.detail.detailItem.gizmos.includes(y.tag))
    )
```

Comment: Sandra - I did try your second suggestion but generates a syntax error on parameters do not match signature.

Comment: how about the first suggestion?